# How implementing lazy loading on Android TV

Tags: android-tv, listrowpresenter

How can lazy loading be implemented in android tv or use recyclerview input leanback? the problem is this:
I get a large list of covers from the server, more than a thousand, there is not enough memory on the physical device and the application hangs. As I understand it, listRow in the ArrayObjectAdapter link in BrowseFragnent renders and stores all the elements at once.

Comment: [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61206740/android-tv-leanback-best-place-to-load-icon-images-to-reduce-memory-footprint?rq=1) help me for solution problem.